# How does my phone start installing apps so quickly when initiated from the play on-line store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, push-notifications

When I go to the Google Play on-line store and install an app, how does my phone know to install it? Is it using push notifications? Quite often it happens within a few seconds so presumably it can't be using polling.

I just don't understand the nature of the connection between my phone and Google's servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's using a push notification via *Google Cloud Messaging* (GCM), the same as Google+ Hangouts, Google+, Gmail, and some third-party apps.

Answer (score 1):

*Google Play* uses [C2DM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2dm) (Cloud to Device Messaging) to inform your device about the download. On your device, the *Google Play Store* app has registered a corresponding "receiver", so it knows this message was meant for it, and downloads the `.apk` – which then gets installed to your device.

And yes, your guess was right: C2DM is also often referred to with the term "push notification".

Comment: [C2DM is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm), and replaced by Google Cloud Messaging, in the Google Play Services library.

Comment: @DanHulme Ah, didn't know that. As a non-dev, I always assumed the two being the same (even the corresponding app permissions are called `c2dm.permission.SEND` resp. `c2dm.permission.RECEIVE`). So thanks for the pointer!